# Checking for property on the object passed to jquery tmpl

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I have a sample data like this:

```
data = {opt1: 'One', opt2:'Two', opt3:'Three'};

tmplString = <li>${opt1}</li><li>${opt2}</li>??IF OPT3?? 

$('#node').append(tmplString, data);
```

In my `tmplString` I want to render `opt3` only if the passed in data has a property called `opt3`. If I use `{{if opt3}}` it throws an error when there is no `opt3` in the data. Is there a way I could use something like `if(prop in obj)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
if(typeof opt3 == "string")
```

Or, if you might have something other than a string in there:

```
if(typeof opt3 != "undefined")
```

Comment: You mean: "{{if typeof ${opt3} != 'undefined'}}"  ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery template syntax, but what I have is plain old js, if that'll work.

Comment: checking the `typeof` will not cause an error to be thrown if the element is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem recently and tried the solution provided by idrumgood.  Unfortunately in my case the data may be null or it may be undefined and

```
typeof null === "object"
```

so using typeof on the value does not distinguish between null and actual data resulting in an error by jquery templates.  I found that if you scope the variable with the $data template variable you can avoid this problem.  For instance, instead of this:

```
{{if opt3}}<li>${opt3}</li>
```

use this:

```
{{if $data.opt3}}<li>${opt3}</li>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheSneak/Yfstb/) demonstrating this solution